# How to display the location of files with Spotlight?

Tags: finder, spotlight

When searching for a file with Spotlight (and with the Finder) I often
find many different versions of the correct file name.

But to choose the correct one I want to deal with, I should see its
complete location on the file system.

I'm hunting a `Makefile`.
Spotlight (the Finder too) displays me a list of a lot of them (I'm working with different package managers which install softwares in
different directories).
How may I quickly display their complete location to choose the one I want?

---

With the command line `find` or `locate` the answer is pretty easy. But in some cases I would like to avoid to start a `Terminal` and fire a pretty long `find`.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you looking for but I have the "Show Path Bar" turned on in Finder, so when I click o a file in the search window it displays the path for it at the bottom of the finder widow.

Comment: Pretty near :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd> to see filepath in Quicklook pop-up.

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted this answer, since this is pretty near of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions:

1. You can try hovering over the file, and a preview of the file will pop-up left of the spotlight list.
2. You can <kbd>⌘</kbd>-click on an item to open its location
3. You can try the free app [Alfred.](http://www.alfredapp.com) Thought I was hesitant first, Alfred has become a replacement for spotlight for me for most purposes. I find that the calculator function of spotlight has many more features, but Alfred is much more extendable. It lists the file paths of results right under the file names.

Comment: In most of the case where I'm searching among many files, I'm not able to recognize these text files from their content. Their location is the only key point which may help me to open the right one.

Comment: → XAleXOwnZX: is your point 3 meaning that Alfred is able to display a list of complete locations when I'm searching for one among 20 `Makefile`?

Comment: Yes @daniel_Azuelos